# Swipe detection in any angle

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition

Is there any way I can detect swipe in iPhone in any angle? `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` seems to have only 4 directions.
If I swipe like this:

```
\
 \
  \
   X
```

I want it to give me something like 60 degrees  and not just down like the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.
How can I do  this?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  When you detect the Ended state you can get the velocity.  The velocity is broken into x and y components.  You can use the x and y components to calculate the slope, m.

> m = ∆y / ∆x

The angle of the line, , defined by the slope, m, relative to the x axis is defined by:

> = arctan(m)

Something like:

```
- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            ...
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
            // If needed: CGFloat slope = velocity.y / velocity.x;
            CGFloat angle = atan2f(velocity.y, velocity.x);
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just detect the start and stop of the touch and calculate the angle with the two points.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//global CGPoint.
    //this should be it's GLOBAL coordinates, not just relative to the view    
    startPoint=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview.superview];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //global CGPoint
    endPoint=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview.superview];
}
```

To calculate the angle between them you could use something like this:

```
static inline CGFloat angleBetweenLinesInRadians(CGPoint line1Start, CGPoint line1End, CGPoint line2Start, CGPoint line2End) {

    CGFloat a = line1End.x - line1Start.x;
    CGFloat b = line1End.y - line1Start.y;
    CGFloat c = line2End.x - line2Start.x;
    CGFloat d = line2End.y - line2Start.y;

    CGFloat line1Slope = (line1End.y - line1Start.y) / (line1End.x - line1Start.x);
    CGFloat line2Slope = (line2End.y - line2Start.y) / (line2End.x - line2Start.x);

    CGFloat degs = acosf(((a*c) + (b*d)) / ((sqrt(a*a + b*b)) * (sqrt(c*c + d*d))));
    return (line2Slope > line1Slope) ? degs : -degs;    
}
//This code came from someone else and I don't remember who to give credit to.
```

So to find the angle off of a horizontal line you could do something like this

```
CGFloat angle=angleBetweenLinesInRadians(startPoint, endPoint, startPoint, CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 10, startPoint.y));
```

That would be the angle like so

```
________
\ this angle
 \
  \
   x
```

Hope this helps

***EDIT*** a better way

What you can do is subclass  UIGestureRecognizer

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

You then implement these methods

```
- (void)reset;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Each of these is used to determine and set the state property for the gesture.

There is a full example here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Comment: Well, I guess I could do that if there is nothing build in. But why go so much trouble getting the angle? `atan2(deltaY, deltaX)` gives you the angle with the quadrants and horizontal/vertical considerations.

Comment: That would definitely be better. I already had that code as I had to find the angle swiping around a center point. But that would be much cleaner.

Comment: You can also subclass UIGestureRecognizer